# How to get response from a http connection in android

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, bufferedreader

I'm trying to handle this API http://worldtimeapi.org
Here is my code :

```
@Nullable
public String getResponseFromHttpUrl(@NonNull URL gotUrl) {

    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "URI : " + gotUrl);
    String timeJSONString = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) gotUrl.openConnection();

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append("\n");
        }

        if (stringBuilder.length() == 0) {
            // Stream was empty. No point in parsing.
            return null;
        }

        timeJSONString = stringBuilder.toString();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        if (bufferedReader != null) {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Response : " + timeJSONString);

    return timeJSONString;
}
```

But the problem is my method returns null.
As you can see in below:

V/NetworkUtils: URI : http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/America/Denver

W/System.err:     at com.example.timeonearth.NetworkUtils.getResponseFromHttpUrl(NetworkUtils.java:56)

D/NetworkUtils: Response : null

Comment: Post the full stack trace.  The problem isn't (or at least likely isn't) something returning null.  Null is what your result object is by default.  Instead, you probably have an IOException, as it was caught but didn't crash.  We just don't know what type, which is important in solving it.

Comment: I tried my code with this API : <https://timeapi.io/api/Time/current/zone?timeZone=Europe/Amsterdam> and it worked. and help me find out that what's the difference between API with 'query' and API with 'path'??

Answer (score -1):

You need to Try getting the input stream from this you can then get the text data as so:-->

```
 URL url;
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
try {
    url = new URL("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/America/Denver");

    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
            .openConnection();

    InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

    InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

    int data = isw.read();
    while (data != -1) {
        char current = (char) data;
        data = isw.read();
        System.out.print(current);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (urlConnection != null) {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }    
}
```

You can probably use other Inputstream readers such as buffered reader also.

The problem is that when you open the connection - it does not 'pull' any data.

Comment: He's doing all that, and the problem is not what you claim here. Your code is no better than his.